# number scale on primefaces charts

Tags: jsf, charts, primefaces

When we create a `primefaces` chart then it shows number scale in decimal points. I want to  show without decimal places like simple munbers.Is there a way?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

While the workaround posted below still works I found a more proper solution to do this. Number scale can be formatted trough `extender` function:

```
<p:barChart value="#{testClazz.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"
            widgetVar="barChartObj1" extender="ext1"/>
```

place the following function between the `<head></head>` tags on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ext1() {
        this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
            formatString : '%d'
        };
    }
</script>
```

---

After experimenting a bit with jqPlot I found out that if you reset the axes after the plotting has finished the decimals after the decimal point are cleared. If your barChart is definied like this:

```
<p:barChart id="basicPlot" value="#{testClazz.categoryModel}" 
    legendPosition="ne" widgetVar="barChartObj"
    title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="270"/>
```

call the following function after the page load is finished:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        setTimeout(formatAxisNumbers, 500);
    });
    function formatAxisNumbers() {
        window.barChartObj.plot.resetAxesScale();
        window.barChartObj.plot.replot();
    }
</script>
```

Note that instead of resetting both axes with `resetAxesScale` you can reset *x* or *y* separately by doing:

`window.barChartObj.plot.axes.xaxis.resetScale();`

or

`window.barChartObj.plot.axes.yaxis.resetScale();`

You can also expriment with decreasing the timeout to smaller numbers to achieve smoother replot.
For other options see the [jqPlot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html).

Tested in Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94 (Official Build 161065).