# Primefaces chart value without points

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have created a simple bar chart using `PrimeFaces`. It is working fine But it shows value in points for instance If I set value `min=0` and `max=200` then it is showing graph points like 
`0 4.44 8.10 12.0 44.6 ...... 200.0`. Is there any way so my chart print like 
 `0 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 200` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the solution posted here: [number scale on primefaces charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739615/number-scale-on-primefaces-charts).

I'm not sure is it possible to get `0 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 200` from `0 4.44 8.10 12.0 44.6 ...... 200.0` but the decimal numbers after the point will be stripped down.